# buscar en un arreglos

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Estoy estudiando programacion y apenas estoy empezando en este mundo,
tengo un proyecto con arreglos y me piden hacer estos tres puntos

• Cuantos seleccionados tienen nombre que empiezan con la letra a.
• Cuantos no seleccionados tienen nombre que terminan con la letra i.
• Mostrar el nombre de los seleccionados cuyo número de cedula es impar.

se que se debe hacer con un for ya que no hemos avanzado mucho y solo estamos trabajando con metodos,arreglos, if, while y el dowhile.
alguien podria ayudarme en estos puntos

mis arreglos vienen de esta manera

```
static int CUPOS = 2; (esto es para asignar la magnitud del arreglo)

static String[] nombres = new String[CUPOS];
static byte[] edades = new byte[CUPOS];
```

Comment: Que pena no es genero es nombre 
static String[] nombres = new String[CUPOS];

Comment: Hola y bienvenido,debes tener presente los puntos para poder elaborar una [correcta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),tal como lo has planteado mas que una ayuda, estas solicitando que se te resuelva la tarea o deber, si bien estas iniciando te aconsejo indagar sobre `charAt()` ,`.length()`,estructurar un codigo y si aun asi tenes inconvenientes,[editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/547575/buscar-en-un-arreglos) agregando el intento de codigo realizado.saludos